# Satisfying the borrow checker with a struct that processes a queue of actions

Tags: design-patterns, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to write a struct which owns some data in a Vec (or perhaps contains a Vec of mutable references - not really important which one), and which can process a queue of "actions", where each action is some sort of calculation which mutates the elements of this Vec. Here is a minimal example of what I have written so far:

```
// some arbitrary data - may be large, so should not be cloned or copied
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct T(i32, &'static str);

struct S(Vec<T>);
impl S {
    fn get_mut(&mut self, t: &T) -> &mut T {
        self.0.iter_mut().find(|a| *a == t).unwrap()
    }
    fn process_actions(&mut self, queue: ActionQueue) {
        // some arbitrary calculation on the elements of self.0
        for a in queue.actions {
            let t1 = self.get_mut(a.t1);
            t1.0 += a.t2.0;
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    ActionError,
    ActionQueueError,
}

struct Action<'a> {
    s: &'a S,
    t1: &'a T,
    t2: &'a T,
}
impl<'a> Action<'a> {
    pub fn new(s: &'a S, t1: &'a T, t2: &'a T) -> Result<Action<'a>, Error> {
        if s.0.contains(&t1) && s.0.contains(&t2) {
            Ok(Action { s, t1, t2 })
        } else {
            Err(Error::ActionError)
        }
    }
}

struct ActionQueue<'a> {
    s: &'a S,
    actions: Vec<Action<'a>>,
}
impl<'a> ActionQueue<'a> {
    pub fn new(s: &'a S, actions: Vec<Action<'a>>) -> Result<ActionQueue<'a>, Error> {
        if actions.iter().all(|a| std::ptr::eq(a.s, s)) {
            Ok(ActionQueue { s, actions })
        } else {
            Err(Error::ActionQueueError)
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let t1 = T(1, "a");
    let t2 = T(2, "b");
    let mut s = S(vec![t1, t2]);

    let a = Action::new(&s, &t1, &t2)?; // error: borrow of moved value: `t1`
    let q = ActionQueue::new(&s, vec![a])?;
    s.process_actions(q); // cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

    Ok(())
}
```

There are a few problems with this:

1. I can't create the Action because t1 and t2 have already been moved.
2. Even if I could, I can't process the action queue because s is already immutably borrowed in the Action. The reason I want the Action (and ActionQueue) to contain a reference to s is because, from what I understand, it's good to use types prevent the creation of invalid data, e.g. an Action (to be processed by s) referring to data not contained in s.
3. The `get_mut` function of S seems a bit weird and hacky, like I shouldn't need to have such a function.

I understand why the errors occur and what they mean, but I don't see any way to get around this problem, because in order to define any Action, I need to refer to elements of `s.0` which I am not allowed to do. So my question is, how should this code be rewritten so that it will actually compile? It doesn't matter if the design is completely different, as long as it achieves the same goal (i.e. allows to queue up actions to be processed later).

Comment: Some clarification please: 1. would there be more than one `ActionQueue` in the same module? 2. Would `S` ever be realistically used as a standalone variable? 3.Are different functions for `S` as a field of `ActionQueue` be acceptable?

Comment: @Esdeseserdt1976 1) I don't think I will need to actually keep any instances of these classes around for longer than the body of one function. I'm creating all of the data, creating one action queue, adding several actions to it, processing the actions, reading the results, and then everything is dropped when the function ends. As for 2) and 3) I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but it doesn't really matter what functions to any of the structs. Whatever is necessary is probably ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the desired behavior by:

1. I changed the references in `T` to `usize` indices, which refer to the same data as before, but now only when an action is being performed, and thus in a new scope. This does require slightly more forethought, and would be a lot more expensive if you moved the `T` items in place (in the `S` vector), since you would need to find the new indices of the items- potentially braking  it (i haven't tested, but don't see why anything more than a simple iteration search would be needed)

2.limiting the number of borrows. I removed the `S` reference in `Action`, which makes this possible, although it sacrifices some reliability (more on that later) it was redundant anyway.

3. The `usize` index search solves the `get_mut()` problem, but also means that now to use the data, you have to refer to the individual fields of `T`. The reason `get_mut()` seems so hacky is because it's essentially a hypercondensed iteration search. It would be really helpful if you move the `T`s inside `S`, so you may want to keep it in your source, but its not needed in this example.

```rust
// some arbitrary data - may be large, so should not be cloned or copied
use std::marker::PhantomData;
struct T(i32, &'static str);
struct S(Vec<T>);
impl S {
    fn process_actions(&mut self, changes: [usize;2]) {
        let mut a = self.0[changes[0]].0;
        a += self.0[changes[1]].0;
        println!("the total is {}",a);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    ActionQueueError,
}

struct Action<'a> {
    t1: usize,
    t2: usize,
    phantom_lifetime: PhantomData<&'a u8>,
}
impl<'a> Action<'a> {
    pub fn new(ts: [usize;2]) -> Action<'a> {
        Action {
            t1: ts[0],
            t2: ts[1],
            phantom_lifetime: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
struct ActionQueue<'a> {
    s: S,
    actions: Vec<Action<'a>>,
}
impl<'a> ActionQueue<'a> {
    pub fn new(s: S, actions: Vec<Action<'a>>) -> Result<ActionQueue<'a>, Error> {
        if actions.iter().all(|a| s.0.len() > a.t1 && s.0.len() > a.t2) {
            Ok(ActionQueue { s, actions })
        } else {
            Err(Error::ActionQueueError)
        }
    }
    pub fn process_many_actions(&mut self) {
        for gos in self.actions.iter_mut() {
            self.s.process_actions([gos.t1,gos.t2])
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let t1 = T(1, "a");
    let t2 = T(2, "b");
    let s = S(vec![t1, t2]);
    let a = Action::new([0,1]);
    let mut q = ActionQueue::new(s, vec![a])?;
    q.process_many_actions();
    Ok(())
}
```

On safety,  you probably  noticed  i removed both checks from the question. the first check was a fairly simple replacement, the only real changes being that now it makes the check when moving into `ActionQueue`  instead
of immediately, and it checks that the indices will find *something*,  not that it will 110% be the same element in that index as when you put it in. The second check is obsolete, since `S` is moved into `ActionQueue` and then changes on a method
to `ActionQueue`. While maybe a bit harder to debug, that will at least make the function calls simpler and safer.

T'was quite the pickle you got yourself in! In the future, to make debugging easier( or at least take less time for answerers, and attract more people... there are other people on this site, I think《?》), keep the rules of rust borrowing in mind *as you write*. This won't eliminate errors, not even close, but should keep you out of as big of trouble you've had.